# Creating a new page in Word through C# when the previous page is full

Tags: c#, image, list, ms-word

I am using C# to create a word document which contains a set of images through interop referencing. I have successfully made the program insert the images one after the other in order from a list, however my problem is that when the images reach the end of the page instead of creating a new page to contain the images which exceed the size of the 1st page, all of the images pile on top of each other at the bottom of the page.

I have found help online on how to create a new page at a chosen point however this will not work very well as for example: If I created a new line after 3 images I could end up with the same error if 3 tall images were used or half of the page wasted if 3 short images were used.

Is there a way to detect when the next image will not fit the page, create a new page and insert the next image onto that page?

This is my current code:

```
    private void CreateDocument()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create an instance for word app
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
            winword.Visible = false;

            //Create a missing variable for missing value
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            //Create a new document
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            object start_ofdoc = "\\startofdoc";

            // Get a range at the start of the document.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range start_range = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref start_ofdoc).Range;

            for (int i = 0; i < chosenQuestions.Count; i++)
            {
                //Add a picture
                string picture_file = chosenQuestions[i];
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape inline_shape = start_range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(picture_file, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // Format the picture.
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape = inline_shape.ConvertToShape();

                // Wrap text around the picture's square.
                shape.WrapFormat.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapSquare;

                // Align the picture on the upper middle.
                shape.Left = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
            }

            //Save the document
            object filename = installLocation + @"\SavedPapers\Test Paper";
            document.SaveAs(ref filename);
            document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            document = null;
            winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            winword = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully!");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call ConvertToShape() ?  An InlineShape is what you need.\

Comment: Pagination is a built-in Word feature and depends on more than just the content, it also depends on the selected printer and paper size.  Don't help.